# eslint and flow gives stacktrace as error

Tags: javascript, babeljs, eslint, yarnpkg, eslint-config-airbnb

I've been following, currently at the flow part: https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch/blob/7271d32d24251898d7e1786e205f8c608e80f54a/tutorial/02-babel-es6-eslint-flow-jest-husky.md#readme

I'm running win10 and I've installed all software using chocolatey (node, yarn ++).

When running yarn test (eslint src && flow) I get the following:

```
yarn test v0.27.5
$ eslint src && flow
can't resolve reference #/definitions/basicConfig from id #
can't resolve reference #/definitions/basicConfigOrBoolean from id #
can't resolve reference #/definitions/basicConfigOrBoolean from id #
Error: node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/src/rules/media-has-caption.js:53
                                                v--------------------------------------
53:       const trackChildren: Array<JSXElement> = node.children.filter((child: Node) => {
54:         if (child.type !== 'JSXElement') {
55:           return false;
...:
60:       });
       -^ call of method `filter`. Function cannot be called on any member of intersection type
53:       const trackChildren: Array<JSXElement> = node.children.filter((child: Node) => {
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ intersection
 Member 1:
 245:     filter(callbackfn: typeof Boolean): Array<$NonMaybeType<T>>;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. See lib: C:\Users\Eivind\AppData\Local\Temp\flow\flowlib_d70c9ae\core.js:245
 Error:
                                                                       v-----------------
 53:       const trackChildren: Array<JSXElement> = node.children.filter((child: Node) => {
 54:         if (child.type !== 'JSXElement') {
 55:           return false;
...:
 60:       });
         ^ statics of function. This type is incompatible with
   v-----------------------
106: declare class Boolean {
107:     constructor(value?: mixed): void;
108:     static (value:any):boolean;
...:
111: }
   ^ statics of Boolean. See lib: C:\Users\Eivind\AppData\Local\Temp\flow\flowlib_d70c9ae\core.js:106
Member 2:
246:     filter(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: Array<T>) => any, thisArg?: any): Array<T>;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. See lib: C:\Users\Eivind\AppData\Local\Temp\flow\flowlib_d70c9ae\core.js:246
 Error:
 4924:   children: Array<Node>;
                      ^^^^ object type. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of. See: node_modules/ast-types-flow/lib/types.js:4924
 53:       const trackChildren: Array<JSXElement> = node.children.filter((child: Node) => {
                                                                               ^^^^ Node

Error: node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/src/rules/media-has-caption.js:59
59:         return isTrackType(context, elementType(child.openingElement));
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `openingElement`. Property not found in
59:         return isTrackType(context, elementType(child.openingElement));
                                                 ^^^^^ Node


Found 2 errors
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Have no idea what any of this is...
I have also had some problems with scripts being unrecognized after using `yarn add package`, but I think i resolved that by fixing a wrong peer dependency for eslint-airbnb-config.

Here are my config files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "js-fullstack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "eslint src && flow",
    "start": "babel-node src"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.51.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
    {
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "compat",
    "flowtype"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "linebreak-style": [2, "windows"],
    "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": 0,
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 2,
    "compat/compat": 2
  }
}
```

.flowconfig

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "flow"
  ]
}
```